# Package 'irr', function 'icc': Unrealistic p-values in output

Tags: r, statistics, irr

I'm getting crazy over this issue:

I'm computing (lots of) ICCs at the moment to assess the retest-reliability of brain-parameters using the function 'icc' in the package 'irr' by Matthias Gamer. However, I noticed several unrealistic p-values in the ouput. For example, a moderate ICC (two variables, no missing values) of .675 in a large sample of N=583 comes with a non-significant p-value of .102, which seems highly unlikely given the moderate effect and the large sample (I caculate thousands of ICCs atm and usually obtain p-values <.001 for ICCs > .200). To be sure, I reproduced the EXACT same ICC using a different software, and obtained the expected p-value <.001 here. However, I would like to use the irr-package for an automated, code-based analysis. This is the code I'm using:

```
library(irr)
load(Example_dataframe)
icc(Example_dataframe, model = "twoway", type = "agreement", unit = "average")
```

And this is the complete output I get:

```
 Average Score Intraclass Correlation

   Model: twoway 
   Type : agreement 

   Subjects = 583 
     Raters = 2 
   ICC(A,2) = 0.675

 F-Test, H0: r0 = 0 ; H1: r0 > 0 
   F(582,2) = 9.27 , p = 0.102 

 95%-Confidence Interval for ICC Population Values:
  -0.237 < ICC < 0.893
```

I noticed that the confidence interval is super large, but an effect of .675 should still be highly significant. It seems that there is a bug in the icc-function, which is confusing as the package is quite popular and has been used for more than a decade. The variables I'm using have no missing values. I tried to contact the maintainer, but received no response.

My questions:

Is there anyone with experience with the 'irr'-package who can help me?
Do you agree that this must be based on a bug?
What else could be the problem?

Any help is highly appreciated, I'm running out of ideas what to do here...

Kind regards,
Tobias

Comment: (i) you might want to migrate that question to CrossValidated. (ii) don't count on an answer without creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).